# Pass a lens into a function

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'd like to perform a sort based on a specific value within a record. As such I was thinking of passing a lens into a `lensSort` function but I've been unable to make it work.

Ideally I could do something like this

```
lensSort :: HasLens a => Lens' a b -> a -> a -> -> Ordering
lensSort lens x y | x ^. lens > y ^. lens = GT
                    | x ^. lens < y ^. lens = LT
                    | otherwise = GT
```

And be able to call it with something like

```
data Rectangle = Rectangle { _height :: Int, _width :: Int }
makeLenses'' Rectangle

let foo = [Rectangle 1 2, Rectangle 2 1]
sortBy (lensSort height) foo
```

I'm failing to get this to work, and concerned I might be barking up the wrong tree completely, I'm still new to Haskell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aside from typos, your code actually works pretty much as it is – the only things that obviously needed is that `b` be in fact comparable. The following works:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, RankNTypes #-}
import Control.Lens
import Control.Lens.TH
import Data.List

data Rectangle = Rectangle { _height :: Int, _width :: Int }
  deriving (Show)
makeLenses ''Rectangle

lensSort :: Ord b => Lens' a b -> a -> a -> Ordering
lensSort lens x y | x ^. lens > y ^. lens = GT
                    | x ^. lens < y ^. lens = LT
                    | otherwise = GT

foo :: [Rectangle]
foo = [Rectangle 1 2, Rectangle 2 1]

main = print $ sortBy (lensSort height) foo
-- [Rectangle {_height = 1, _width = 2},Rectangle {_height = 2, _width = 1}]
```

Note that there is not really a need to pass around an actual lens, because you only use it as a getter (≅function) anyway. So you can just do

```
import Data.Ord (comparing)
main = print $ sortBy (comparing (^.height))
```

...without any extra definitions.

Answer (score 4):

You can implement your `sortByLens` - or rather `sortByGetting` function. Starting with your definitions

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module Test where

import Control.Lens
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List (compare, sortBy)

data Rectangle = Rectangle { _height :: Int, _width :: Int }
$(makeLenses ''Rectangle)
```

we will start to create your desired function in ghci:

```
stack ghci test.hs --package lens

> import Control.Lens
> import Data.Function
> import Data.List
> :t sortBy
sortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
> :t on
on :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c
> :t compare
compare :: Ord a => a -> a -> Ordering
```

putting these together with your approach

```
>:t sortBy (compare `on` (view height))
sortBy (compare `on` (view height)) :: [Rectangle] -> [Rectangle]
```

to get this a bit more general we do the following

```
>:t \lens -> sortBy (compare `on` (view lens))
\lens -> sortBy (compare `on` (view lens)) :: Ord a => Getting a s a -> [s] -> [s]
```

and so we can define

```
sortByGetting :: Ord a => Getting a s a -> [s] -> [s]
sortByGetting g = sortBy (compare `on` view g)
```

Comment: You can also just use [`sortOn`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortOn): `sortOnGetting g = sortOn (view g)`

Comment: @jpath thx - for some reason I always forget that this function exists!